# How to check if fragment isVisible() when added by XML layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am adding a fragment with XML layouts.  It displays fine all works well.  Why is isVisible() always returning false ???  How do I check fragment Visibility when adding with XML ?
-Thank You.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history_activity_layout);
        Log.d("myLog",".....key1= setContentView");

         mF= new HistoryOFragMast();


         //  Test:  add with code : isVisible still = false
//          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
//          fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment1p, mF, "myMaster");
//          fragmentTransaction.commit();



            fMasterP= (HistoryOFragMast) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1p);
            Log.d("myLog",".....key1= fMasterP NULL= "+fMasterP);
            Log.d("myLog",".....key1= fMasterP vis= "+fMasterP.isVisible());....}
```

my xml is `history_activity_layout.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1p"
        android:name="com.pakage.O.HistoryOFragMast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:
Moved code to onResume() to make sure I have reached the end of the Avctivity\Fragment Lifcyle.  Still get "false" for isVisible() ???

Comment: Because the fragment is not visible until well after the `onCreate()` method finishes.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just moved visibilty check to Activity onStart() still getting false.  thanks.

Comment: This means you are still checking too soon. Apparently the fragment still isn't visible yet in `Activity.onStart()`.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve here? Why do you need to check if the fragment is visible?

Comment: I have a Master\Detail App that needs to set some interface callbacks depending on Portrait or Landscape if(DetailFragment!=null && DetailFragment.isVisible()  ) then..we are in Landscper... fMasterL.setCommunicatorHistory(this);.   Let me try Activity onResume...??? back in sec.

Comment: Another solution is to have a single callback which detects landscape/portrait mode (or calls `isVisible()` on the fragment) when the callback's hook method is called. You should be able to design the callbacks in such a way that they will only be called after the fragment is indeed displayed and visible, if at all.

Comment: That actually sounds like a good idea.  Let me give it a shot. (still would like to know why isVisible returns false in onResume). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, to check if the fragment is visible to the user (you have to use it inside the HistoryOFragMast fragment class)

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //Code to do when visible here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `onCreate()` method is in the `Activity` that contains your `Fragment`. Note that the fragment is not even inflated at this point and it certainly is not visible. You need to detect whether the fragment is visible later in the activity's life cycle.